# What is a Immutable htaccess file and how do you create one?

Tags: php, .htaccess

What is a Immutable htaccess file? I read that it's supposed to be securety from/for php files. I don't fully understand it, How does it work? and how do you create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

immutable file means, that you can't delete or modify the file anymore

to set the immutable attribute on unix

```
 chattr +i .htaccess
```

Comment: try it out: php example <?php touch('foo.bar');exec('chattr +i foo.bar'); var_dump(unlink('foo.bar'));